# How to create a translucent Progress Dialog in android

Tags: android

I have googled a lot and even gone through many of this website questions but I just can't find the solution to my problem.

I want to create a Progress Dialog like the one below.But i don't understand how to do it..I have tried by creating a custom progress dialog but..with that you can only modify the inside spinner appearance..In my case i want to modify its layout...How can i achieve that...????

Till now i have tried the following...

```
public class nextclass extends Activity {

    Thread t;
    ProgressBar dia;

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MainActivity.progressDialog.dismiss();
        setContentView(R.layout.nextclassview);
    //  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1))
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        // progressDialog = findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

                        new AuthenticateUserTask().execute();
                    }
                });
    }

    private class AuthenticateUserTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
                    nextclass.this, "","Sucessful", true);
/*            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);

            progressDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources()
                    .getDrawable(R.layout.customspinner));
*/


            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(nextclass.this, "",
                    "Processing....", true);
            progressDialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            if (progressDialog.isShowing())
                progressDialog.dismiss();

            Intent my = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CountTime.class);
            startActivity(my);

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);![custom spinner][2]
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [this link](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application) for details on how to create a custom Dialog

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams WMLP = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();


     WMLP.x = 100;   //x position
     WMLP.y = 100;   //y position

     dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(WMLP);
```

**Edit2:**
Make a Dialog Activity with your code in it sample is shown below

```
public class DialogActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle(" ");
        alertDialog.setMessage("");
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
        alertDialog.setButton("Accept", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {                
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setButton2("Deny", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

and in android manifest file

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

**OR**

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.popup_theme));
```

in the values folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="back_color">#ffffffff</color>
<style name="popup_theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/back_color</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/back_color</item>
</style>
```

Comment: No not working....I want the Progress Dialog to occupy only 80% of the screen...The rest of the screen can be used by the user....for eg..The button on the top right is a custom logout button..It should be clickable..

Comment: I guess you can include the Log out button and other view you want in custom Dialog and give a background image or color to it,Make Dialog 100% of the screen or you can check my edited answer for making dialog appear at a certain position and you can set other attributes too.

Comment: ok..the only problem now is that the dialog is not transparent....how can i make it transparent...i made the custom dialog background transparent but not working....

Comment: Well I guess the tint which is shown is because it has a black color with alpha value less than 60 I guess not sure can you Edit and put a screen shot as how its looking now so that I can help

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a rotation animation in the anim folder for this as:

```
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@anim/linear_interpolator"
>
<rotate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="360"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="51%"
android:repeatCount="infinite"
android:duration="800" />

</set>
```

Create a Image View in XML as:

```
      <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/loading"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/splash"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:background="@drawable/load_spinner" />
```

Use the following code:

```
       Animation mRotateAnim;
       ImageView mImgVwRotatingImage;
           mImgVwRotatingImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading);
       mRotateAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_anim);


private class splashAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mImgVwRotatingImage.startAnimation(mRotateAnim);
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(first.this, second.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: can u tell me where to put the first part of xml code i.e the set and rotate property....

Comment: and in the image view....The background will be only spinner or the spinner and the text both???

Comment: I guess if you use ProgresBar widget you wont need imageview and animation ? check it out in GUI of your xml in FormWidget just drag and drop if your using eclipse, you can make a layout with textView and ProgressBar