# how to adjust android custom dialog to make original layout dim?

Tags: android, dialog

I think in normal situation, when I open an Android dialog, the original view will be dark and I can focus the view on dialog and it will restore after I close the dialog . But now, I try to make a custom dialog with XML by `dialog.setContentView`. In this the time, the original activity view will not dim, how can I adjust ?

I found from Internet this method
but it doesn't work, and others say the same.
Does anyone know why?

`WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
lp.dimAmount=0.6f;
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);`

I think the way below is scaring
`dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);`

->
I find maybe it's my activity problem. I use a custom dialog view activity from android sample code. It use android:style/Theme.Dialog. Now in this dialog activity, I hope I can open a real dialog, and the dialog activity can dim.

Comment: please check the link [here][1] hope it will help


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063816/how-to-create-a-translucent-progress-dialog-in-android/13063904#13063904

Comment: I am not sure your commend. can you explain it. I use  Dialog dialog to complete my custom dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a ProgressDialog:

```
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
    progressDialog.setMessage("test");
    progressDialog.show();
```

This dims the background in my tests.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
lp.dimAmount=0.0f;
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```

Comment: i try this before, but it doesn't work too. I can use dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND); but I think it's too scaring